# ImageMagick: Tiff to PDF from PHP

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick, tiff

How can I convert 2 tiff images to PDF, I already knows how to get the image out of the DB, and I print it using echo and setting up the MIME type.

But, right know I need to use a duplex printer option, so I need a way to generate a PDF from inside my PHP page, that PDF must containt both TIFF images (one per page) How can I do that? What do I need for php to work with that library.

Thank you very much.

EDIT:

Is a self hosted app, I own the server (actually I'm using WAMP 2).

I extract the images from the MySQL DB (stored using LONGBLOBS).

Comment: Please go more into detail about your setup. Do you have ImageMagick already running? Can you access ImageMagick from PHP? Are you talking about CMYK TIFFs? Are you on an own server, or shared hosting?

Comment: Hi, I don't have the ImageMagick installed, only knew about it by searching here.

Is our own server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really need is a library that brings you a PDF composition engine. And of course you need that engine to support image insertions (specifically TIFF).

The best option is iText.

```
public void createPdf(String filename) throws DocumentException, IOException 
{
   // step 1
    Document document = new Document();
    // step 2
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(filename));
    // step 3
    document.open();
    // step 4
    document.add(new Paragraph("PDF Title"));
    // step 5
    document.add(new Image("Tiff image path..."));
    // step 6
    document.close();
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: The OP asked how to do it in PHP, not Java.

Answer (score 2):

There is a very simple PHP script that interfaces with ImageMagick:

[**How to convert multipage TIFF to PDF in PHP**](http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/php_tiff2pdf/)

I haven't used it myself but it looks all right.
For this you will need

- ImageMagick installed
- Ghostscript installed

the linked article describes how to install those in a Ubuntu Linux environment.

Another road to take would be inserting the images directly into a auto-generated PDF file without ImageMagick. The best-known PDF generation library, [**FPDF**](http://www.fpdf.org/), can do this, [**but for JPEG, PNG and GIF only**](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/image.htm).

Maybe one of these works for you.

Comment: Link is dead as of 2016, according to archive.org.  For anybody else looking, the page can now be found here: http://kvz.io/blog/2007/11/28/php-tiff2pdf/

Answer (score -1):

Using imagick library, below solution worked for me  -

```
$document = new Imagick($path."/".$fileName.tiff);
$data = $document->getImageBlob();
$document->setImageFormat("pdf");
$document->writeImages($path."/".$fileName.pdf, true);
```